# What is the best way to iterate through a JSON object and print elements to the screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm just trying to learn the most efficient way to manipulate JSON data and slap it up on the screen. I'm a noob so try to break your answer down clearly if you can. Javascript and jQuery solutions welcome. Something like this:

---

**Meats**

- NY Strip $20.00
- Ribeye $19.00

**Vegetables**

- Kale $4.00
- Sunchokes $3.20

---

This is the JSON object (could it be rewritten more efficiently?):

```
var foods = { 
   "category":{
       "Meats":[
           {
              "product":"NY Strip",
              "price":20.00,
              "cost":14.00,
              "total sold": 3
           },
           {
              "product":"Ribeye",
              "price":20.00,
              "cost":14.00,
              "total sold": 6
           }
       ],
       "Vegetables":[
           {
              "product":"Kale",
              "price":4.00,
              "cost":2.00,
              "total sold": 10
           },
           {
              "product":"Sunchokes",
              "price":3.20,
              "cost":1.00,
              "total sold": 5
           }
       ]
    }
}
```

---

Here is my attempt: (wish I knew of a way to incorporate the category titles into the loops instead of hard coding them.)

```
<h3>Meats</h3>
<script>
    for(key in foods.category.Meats){
       document.write("<li>" + foods.category.Meats[key].product + " $" + foods.category.Meats[key].price + "</li>"); 
    }
</script>
<h3>Vegetables</h3>
<script>
    for(key in foods.category.Vegetables){
       document.write("<li>" + foods.category.Vegetables[key].product + " $" + foods.category.Vegetables[key].price + "</li>"); 
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will iterate through your entire object.

```
var category = foods.category

for(var cat in category) {
  if(category.hasOwnProperty(cat)) {
    category[cat].forEach(function(item) {
      console.log(item);
      // Do stuff here
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:

```
Object.keys(foods.category).forEach(function(category) {
    foods.category[category].forEach(function(item) {
       console.log('do stuff with', item);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks y'all. So I should delve into the forEach() method when iterating through objects? Is there any way you could go ahead and write out the categories along with the products like in my example to fully grasp how this all works? Is there a way to write out category, product, product, category, product, product with a single forEach() method?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, thanks y'all.

```
var category = foods.category

        for(var key in category) {
          if(category.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            category[key].forEach(function(item) {
                if(document.getElementById(key) === null){
                    document.write("<h4" + " id='" + key + "'" + ">" + key + "</h4>")
                }

              document.write("<li>" + item.product + "</li>");
            });
          }
        }
```